# Xamarin C# iAd Banner view Bottom example

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, iad, ads

I created an IOS App in Xamarin and I want to have an iAd view at the bottom of the only View (SingleView). I only found solutions for multi-view Apps and so on, but I just want a simple iAd view at the bottom. How I can do that? I searched Xamarin and Apple Dev. help, but I could not find anything helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I used AdMob because I was having issues with iAd. I was using Xamarin.Forms, but the custom renderer is the same code that would go in a regular iOS app.

https://github.com/valdetero/SevenDays/tree/master/SevenDays.UI/SevenDays.UI.iOS/Renderers

Maybe this will give you enough to start.

iAd:

```
var adBannerView = new ADBannerView(new System.Drawing.Rectangle(0, 386, 320, 50));
```

Admob:

```
adView = new GADBannerView(size: GADAdSizeCons.Banner)
{
    AdUnitID = adMobElement.AdUnitId,
    RootViewController = UIApplication.SharedApplication.Windows[0].RootViewController
};

adView.AdReceived += (sender, args) =>
{
    if (!viewOnScreen) this.AddSubview(adView);
        viewOnScreen = true;
};

adView.LoadRequest(GADRequest.Request);
```

And then just add this to your view.

Comment: Hey, thank you for your answer. I did not know that google AdMob can be used in IOS too. I worked with AdMob in my Android app, but I don't know how to use it in Xamarin.IOS. I tried your example and did research on the internet, but it does not work, maybe I need some packages to install, but I don't know which ones and where to find them. I searched through all using's, but I did not find anything with Google, GAD, or Ad in it, please help me.

Comment: Sorry, it isn't a nuget package but a Xamarin component: https://components.xamarin.com/view/googleiosmobileads.